# Convert object returned by SOAP service to XML/JSON in Cassandra DB

Tags: java, xml, soap, cassandra, jaxb

I have a soap service which is returning the object similar to below:

```
@XmlRootElement
// order of the fields in XML
// @XmlType(propOrder = {"price", "name"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Fruit {

    @XmlAttribute
    int id;

    @XmlElement(name = "n")
    String name;

    String price;

    // getter, setter and toString...
}
```

This object is returned as XML which I want to store, the above file is generated from wsdl.

Is there way to convert this object to String and store as blob in cassandra DB or converting it to json will also work.
I tried converting it to string using toString() and unmarshalling it as well, but it is not working.
Is it possible to directly convert it into string or I need to use mapper?

Comment: Could you explain what is not working with unmarshalling ? If you need to read back data and go back to pojo form, marshalling / unmarshalling is a good option (or with json equivalent (objectMapper toString / parse))